# Client stuck downloading website source c#

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, webclient

I am trying to download a websites source code, as soon as I press the button to start retrieving, the programm would stuck infinitely

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                string html = client.DownloadString("https://www.finanzen.net/termine/unternehmen/");
                MessageBox.Show(html);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue ? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and see  what causing this behavior.

Comment: `WebClient` is outdated already, you should use `HttpClient` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking too much from the poor `MessageBox.Show`. The `html` is `423,467` chars long. Try this instead:

```
MessageBox.Show(html.Substring(0, Math.Min(html.Length, 1000)));
```

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer to use the asynchronous implementations of the methods. See the example below:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                string html = await client.DownloadStringAsync("https://www.finanzen.net/termine/unternehmen/");
                MessageBox.Show(html);
            }
        }
```

Edit:
Instead of displaying the results in a MessageBox I would suggest that you add a DataGrid in your GUI. The results will be stored in a list and then displayed on the GUI.

Comment: We don't answer what we "prefer" here. This also wouldn't compile, as an event handler must return `void` (`Task` is invalid)

Comment: You cannot await `DownloadStringAsync`, that method is event-driven, it doesn't return an awaitable Task. The async, awaitable, *version* is `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.